# How to set parameter from *.properties into SPRING appContext.xml if i set location with JVM variable?

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, jvm

I have a VM parameter `-Dapp.conf=/path/to/config.properties` and i have a appContext.xml for my Spring 4.2.5 application.
This `config.properties` contains propertis like `database.username=username`

in the  XML config i have this bean `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value= "${database.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>`

i'm trying to read my config files using this:

```
 `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="location" value="file:///#{systemEnvironment['app.conf']}"/>
</bean>`
```

But my inserted parameters `value= "${database.driver}` not reading from file.

How i may insert my parameters from my properties file to a my DataSource?

in this case its just inserts `${database.driver}` and i have exception, that parameter is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Spring BOOT i've made this and its worked:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (Reader reader =
                 new FileReader(
                         System.getProperty("app.conf")
                       //this contains path:"D://config.properties"
                 )) {
        properties.load(reader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    for (String propertyName: properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        System.setProperty(propertyName, properties.getProperty(propertyName));
    }
```

this code loads my properties as VM parameters, and i can access them with Spring annotation `@Value("#{property.name}")`

I don't know why, but `System.setProperties(properties);` not worked.